# Server tags and specific server settings in Release Management

Tags: deployment, release-management, ms-release-management

Using MS Release Management (v2015) we can use tags to deploy our applications to multiple servers sharing the same tag.
This is useful for identical servers in a load-balanced environment.
But how to do sever-specific actions using server tags, such as setting a website binding to the server's IP address?

As far as I can see there are no variables to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Tags are intended to run the exact same set of actions. If you have server-specific activities, you'll have to break those out into separate server containers.

I've done exactly that before, for exactly the same situation.

Comment: Thanks. I can do only the set_binding command inside a parallel action containing several servers and then continue the flow using the Tag again. Right?